# Scilab/Octave in the cloud (parallel processing)

Tags: cloud, octave, distributed-computing, openstack, scilab

Is it possible to launch Scilab/Octave (or any other free numerical computational software) on multiple instances and start parallel processing? I have seen that it is possible with Matlab, but it's commercial software.

I planned to deploy Scilab/Octave into Openstack instances.

Is there any other software that you could recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give [Julia](http://julialang.org/) a try. It supports message passing parallelism: http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/

You run it with the `-p` flag to indicate how many processes you want to use in the cluster:

```
julia -p nprocs main.jl
```

The language is quite new though, you won't always find documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try!

I have also found SciPy and NumPy useful:
http://www.scipy.org/getting-started.html ,
http://andy.terrel.us/blog/2012/09/27/starting-with-python/